# How to allow users to sp_configure to execute fileexist and cmdshelll

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, configure

In a stored procedure, i execute `master.dbo.sp_fileexist` and `master.dbo.xp_cmdshell` and it's work really good when i'm using `SA` user, but when i use my `db_owner` user, i have this error.

```
[FR]
Msg 15247, Niveau 16, État 1, Procédure sp_configure, Ligne 94
L'utilisateur n'est pas autorisé à effectuer cette action.
[/FR]
[EN]
Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_configure, Line 94 
The user is not authorized to perform this action.
[/EN]
```

But i need too use sp_configure to allow xp_cmdshell.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced option', '1';
Reconfigure
Exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
Reconfigure
```

If someone can help me, please.

Comment: Even if this other user does need to be able to *use* `xp_cmdshell`, do they really need the ability to *enable* and *disable* the feature itself? Shouldn't the feature just be enabled once and that be the end of the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For users that are not members of the sysadmin role on the SQL Server instance you need to do the following actions to grant access to the xp_cmdshell extended stored procedure. 
*A system administrator can enable the use of 'xp_cmdshell' by using sp_configure.*

- Enable the xp_cmdshell procedure:

  ```
  EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
  RECONFIGURE
  GO

  EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
  RECONFIGURE
  GO
  ```
- Grant EXEC permission on the xp_cmdshell stored procedure:

```
    GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_cmdshell TO [Domain\TestUser]
```

---

To do it yourself you need **serveradmin or sysadmin privileges** privs for that

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create a stored procedure with sp_configure to allow xp_cmdshell in it and use even parameters to pass to the sp_configure procedure, create a procedure with execute as owner, than grant execute for this procedure to the users you like :)

I think that by this way you are doing things correctly and safely

I hope this will help you.

Good Luck